# Drools, graph traversal, query to find root nodes

Tags: graph, drools, traversal

I have a Java-side class with essential behaviour like:

```
declare Datum
    description: String
    broader: List <Datum>
    narrower: List <Datum>
end
```

I want to write

```
query rootDatumsFor(Datum datum)
```

that provides a list of the root datums - that is, work "up" the broader property and return a list of each datum that has an empty broader list.

I am getting totally confused how to write this - mainly because of the negation involved.

I think I want something like

```
query rootDatumsFor( Datum datum )
    not Datum() from $datum.broader
    or
    rootDatumsFor( $datum.broader )
end
```

But I am getting confused on both parts. If there are no broader terms, which the **not** should detect, how do I "return" the current value of $datum? I feel each part wants a $result and I want to do a **$result: $datum** but that isn't valid.

And I'm not certain how to do the recursion. Should I have rootDatumsFor(datum, result) and do it via binding?

I've seen examples that do things likes **Datum( this == $datum)** but that doesn't seem to be accepted when I try it.

Any assistance, whilst I keep re-reading the docn to find a little clue how to proceed, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To find all Datum facts with an empty `broader`list, all you have to do is

```
query rootDatumsFor( Datum $datum )
    $datum: Datum( broader.size() == 0 )
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my request. Rather than all root datums, I want just the root datums for a specific datum.